# Executing a script as another user still cause some permission trouble

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts, minecraft

I have to execute this script with PHP. The user `www-data` can't do it, so I modified the `sudoers` file:

```
www-data ALL=(user2) NOPASSWD: /home/user2/bin/test.sh
```

The script is executed in php with this command :

```
sudo -u user2 /home/user2/bin/test.sh
```

Here is `test.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Stopping previous server
screen -S minecraft -X stuff "stop^M"
#deleting the map file
rm -Rf /home/minecraft/Serveur/*/  
# deleting the properties file
rm -f /home/minecraft/Serveur/server.properties 
#new server properties
cp /home/minecraft/MapsEtServ.prop/Bloody/server.properties /home/minecraft/Serveur/server.properties
#new map
cp -R /home/minecraft/MapsEtServ.prop/Bloody/'Bloody Mess v1.0' /home/minecraft/Serveur/'Bloody Mess v1.0' 
#launching the game server
screen -dmS minecraft java -Xmx4096M -Xms4096M -jar  /home/minecraft/Serveur/minecraft_server.jar nogui
```

`/home/minecraft/Serveur` and `/home/minecraft/MapsEtServ.prop` permissions are set to 777.

What happens when I execute the script via SSH: everything works fine.

But when I execute it with php: the screen is stopped, the files are paste and the screen is launched. But there is a problem: the game server is not running.

EDIT : The Probleme is solved !
I just added a cd /home/minecraft/Serveur/ at the beginning of the script and everything works just fine :)

Comment: I just edited it, line 3 it is -Rf not -rf. I works, just tested and I created it by myself.

Comment: no they are not :) I just add them here to clarify my question. i don't get what you mean by where it work.

Comment: In php, what is the result of this line: `<?php echo shell_exec('whoami'); ?>`

Comment: the result is www-data. If i execute the script without changing user, I can't acces the screen because it is owned by www-data. Now, the other user is the owner of the screen.

Comment: So I modified visudo sorry, my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From terminal, using `sudo visudo` command, edit `sudoers` file, and add the following line exactly as it is:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/user2/bin/test.sh
```

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Allowing_other_users_to_run_sudo in this sense.

Then, in php use only `sudo /home/user2/bin/test.sh` command. For example:

```
<?php shell_exec('sudo /home/user2/bin/test.sh'); ?>
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said. This is really weird, the server started, the map folder and the properties were cp, but the server completly ignored those two and he generated another map as if there where no map folder in the same folder ...

Comment: /home/minecraft/Serveur is not the default home directory of the minecraft user. When I launch the same script with the user minecraft, it works.

Comment: @Babajaga In php, what is the result of this line: <?php echo shell_exec('echo $HOME'); ?>

Comment: Nothing, its shows nothing.

Comment: I can't change the script. I have a lots of other files in the /home/minecraft/Serveur folder

Comment: @Babajaga Ok, don't change it. Then set a home directory for `www-data` user. To do this, edit `/etc/passwd` file (with `sudo gedit /etc/passwd` for example), find `www-data` user and add `/home/minecraft` directory for him. Something like: `www-data:x:1002:1002:www-data:/home/minecraft:/bin/sh`. Add only the directory name, nothing else!